# Listing files from a path different that root, C# Google Drive SDK

Tags: c#, list, google-api, google-drive-api

I was trying to list files from a specific folder with the Google Drive v2 SDK but I have troubles with it.
If I want to list files from my 'root' folder it is easy to do, because I can write in the q parameter 'root' in parents. But I cannot get an easy way to list files from my path "/folder1/pictures". The only solution that I found is listing folders from 'root', get the 'folder1' id, then I list folders from there, get the 'pictures' id, and then I search for files with q parameter with the pictures id in parents. That solutions requires so many queries, and it is not performant. Is there any way to make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

In order to to list files in /folder/pictures you will need its ID. There are three ways you can do this...

1. Recurse the directories as you are doing.
2. Look directly for "pictures". If the user has more than one "pictures" folder, then check the parents for each one to see which one is owned by "folder1"
3. Whichever of 1 or 2 you so, you can store the ID of pictures in some local storage, so subsequent searches are a single GET